# Is it possible to persist all object from a list except the one which got failed in grails. if yes how?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, transactional

My goal is prevent rollback of all object from a list in case one gets runtime exception.

I have two domain classes

```
class Payment {
    String orderNo;
    String transactionId;
    String orderTotal;
    Date paymentDate;
}

class Order extends {
    static hasMany = [items: ItemModel];
    String orderNo;
    String customerNumber;
    Date orderDate;
}
```

When i iterate through a list of Order objects, 
    in side createOrder() new instance of Order is created
    then i call makePayment() in which new instance of Payment is created.

It works fine if there is no exception.

However if exception occurs while saving Payment instance, it rolls back all instances of both Payment and Order.

how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to suggest something if your code (probably service?) that creates payments is such a top-sercret-thing that you can't show even a small sample of it.

But anyway you can try add @Transactional annotation not to the entire service class but to certain methods:

```
@Transactional
public someMethod() {
    //some logic
}

public createPayment() {
    //the logic that you're afraid to share
}
```

So the createPayment() method should not be rolled back.